# File method with removing lines

Tags: c#

I am working on a method that reads txt file with multiple lines and then turns it into a txt file with only single line.

Like this:

```
first line,
second line,
third line.
```

Into this:

```
first line, second line, third line.
```

I have this code but it only shows "third line." in file:

MAIN:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fLine= "first line,\n second line,\n third line.";
        string sLine= "";

        Console.Write(fLine);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(sLine);

        string filDat1 = "D:\\Dat1.txt";
        string filDat2 = "D:\\Dat2.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filDat1))
            Console.WriteLine("File already exist!");
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filDat1, fLine);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filDat2, sLine);

        changeFile(filDat1);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

METHOD:

```
    public static void changeFile(string name)
    {
        StringBuilder dato;
        string filDat2 = "D:\\Dat2.txt";

        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(name);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Words in file: " + line);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("New words in new file: ");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string line1 = line;
                dato = new StringBuilder();
                line1 = line1.Replace("\n", " ");
                for (int i = 0; i < line1.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (!line1[i].Equals(""))
                    {
                        dato.Append(line1[i] + "");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(dato);
                File.WriteAllText(filDat2, dato.ToString());
            }

        }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I only get the last word in my case "third word." in new file Dat2.txt.

Also, is there any way to create a method that can take two files. One file to read and one file to write that changed text to it?

Comment: Yes, I would like that file Dat2.txt contains all text that is in Dat1.txt but in single line.

Comment: does this even compile? You are using `line` outside it's scope

Comment: @Sayse I edited vrstice into lines as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to make anew file for given file with only 1 line:

```
  public static void changeFile(string InputPath,string OutputPath)
    {

            List<string> OUTPUT = new List<string>();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InputPath);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                OUTPUT.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            sr.Close();
            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(OutputPath);
            string output = "";

            foreach (string line in OUTPUT)
            {
                output += line + " ";
            }
            fs.WriteLine(output);
            fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were curious as to why your approach didn't work, it was because you reset `dato` every iteration, just move that outside and away you go, I've also moved the write outside too since you only need to do that once.

```
dato = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
     string line1 = line;
    line1 = line1.Replace("\n", " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < line1.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (!line1[i].Equals(""))
        {
            dato.Append(line1[i] + "");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dato);
}
File.WriteAllText(filDat2, dato.ToString());
```